# LWC download PDF file

Tags: lightning, lightning-community, lightning-web-components

I use LWC components in Customer Community.
There is `datatable` component with records and I implemented the function to export selected records in `.csv` and `.pdf`.

`csv` works fine, but I experience the next issue when downloading the file as `pdf`:
[image]

Here is the code I use to create and download the file:

*main.js*

```
handleExportAction(evt) {
    const selectedFormat = evt.detail.value;
    try {
        let _file;
        let _type;
        switch (selectedFormat) {
            case 'csv':
                _file = parseToCSV(this.columns, this.selectedRows);
                _type = 'text/html';
                break;
            case 'pdf':
                _file = parseToPDF(this.columns, this.selectedRows);
                _type = 'application/pdf';
                break;
            default:
                _file = undefined;
                _type = undefined;
        }
        downloadDataAsFile('Subscription Overview.' + selectedFormat, _type, _file);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

*service.js - parse&donwloadFile functions*

```
const parseToPDF = (tableCols, rows) => {
    let cols = [];
    tableCols.filter(el => cols.push('<th>' + el.label));

    let fileData = '<html><head>';
    fileData += '<title>Subscription Overview</title>';
    fileData += '<body><table>';
    fileData += '<tr>';
    fileData += cols.map(col => col).join('</th>') + '</th>';
    fileData += '</tr>';
    fileData += '<tr>';
    fileData += '<td>Test Data</td>';
    fileData += '</tr>';
    fileData += '</body></html>';
    console.log('file: ' + fileData);

    return fileData;
};

const downloadDataAsFile = (name, type, data) => {
var file = new Blob([data], { type: type });
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // IE10+
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
} else { // Others
    var a = document.createElement("a"),
        url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = name;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 0);
}
};
```

The body `(fileData)` variable is for testing purposes, I tried other options but the result was the same.

Probably the issue is in `contentType` which I set as `application/pdf`?

I did not find any limitations related to creating `pdf` files with `js`.
Did someone experienced this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is not a valid PDF content, this is why you can't open the generated file.

Because of the complexity of the PDF specification, I would recommend using existing javascript libraries like [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/) or use APIs to generate PDFs.

Comment: pdfkit is not a suitable solution. I tried jsPDF, it works but the downloaded pdf file cannot be open. There is an error: Failed to load PDF document.
So, I`m looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

As per other answer, you need to correctly generate PDF.

It's easier to create Visual Force page with `renderAs="pdf"` and pass the arguments of rendering to VF page (e.g. a set of IDs).
You can force it to download using header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf'`.

Comment: Erm, yes it does provide the answer?

Comment: is there any reference for this solution?